# Travel to Ireland on a Standard Visitor Visa for business meeting/conference

Tags: indian-citizens, ireland, standard-visitor-visas

Can I travel to Ireland on a UK Standard Visitor visa on Indian passport for the purpose of attending a conference?

Answer (score -1):

You *should* be fine

1. Ireland/UK have special relationship (I'm Irish)
2. There has never been passport checks between Ireland/UK.

Enjoy!